# Recent update killed unity 3d launcher

Tags: 12.04, unity, updates

I am scratching my head on this one, a lot of things are still new to me.

I updated 126 packages just now through the update manager, and upon reboot everything works fine except the unity launcher.  It's just a dark space.  The dash still works, as does the top panel and docky.

When I try:

```
unity --replace
```

I end up with this and then an indefinite hang:

```
(compiz:3689): GConf-CRITICAL **: gconf_client_add_dir: assertion `gconf_valid_key (dirname, NULL)' failed
WARN  2012-09-23 02:18:29 unity.favorites FavoriteStoreGSettings.cpp:139 Unable to load GDesktopAppInfo for 'ubiquity-gtkui.desktop'
WARN  2012-09-23 02:18:30 unity.favorites FavoriteStoreGSettings.cpp:139 Unable to load GDesktopAppInfo for 'ubuntuone-installer.desktop'
ERROR 2012-09-23 02:18:30 unity.launcher.trashlaunchericon TrashLauncherIcon.cpp:62 Could not create file monitor for trash uri: Operation not supported
Initializing unityshell options...done
WARN  2012-09-23 02:18:31 unity.libindicator <unknown>:0 Desktop file '/usr/share/applications/libreoffice-writer.desktop' is using a deprecated format for its actions that will be dropped soon.
WARN  2012-09-23 02:18:31 unity.libindicator <unknown>:0 Desktop file '/usr/share/applications/libreoffice-calc.desktop' is using a deprecated format for its actions that will be dropped soon.
WARN  2012-09-23 02:18:31 unity.libindicator <unknown>:0 Desktop file '/usr/share/applications/libreoffice-impress.desktop' is using a deprecated format for its actions that will be dropped soon.
Setting Update "main_menu_key"
Setting Update "run_key"
```

Unfortunately I cannot make heads or tails of this.  Anyone, please help?

Comment: Trying to open the HUD crashes unity.

Comment: have you reset Unity or logged out and back in?

Comment: Strange!! How this question be off-topic?

Comment: Any chance you installed CCSM (CompizConfig Settings Manager) and played around with the settings? Any other clues or was this a stable and not highly customised system before the errors appeared?

Comment: There weren't that many customizations through CCSM except for wobbly windows, and it was stable after I changed the load order with...  I think it was dconf.  However, I do suspect KDE.  I had installed the plasma package to play with it, but when I went to remove it, the update manager refused to not download updates for it.  I don't understand it at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. First try to remove lenses and reinstall them again.

   ```
   sudo apt-get remove --purge unity-lens-applications unity-lens-music unity-lens-files unity-lens-videos
   ```
2. Then remove the `~/.cache` dir

   ```
   rm -r ~/.cache
   ```
3. Then install them again

   ```
   sudo apt-get install unity-lens-applications unity-lens-music unity-lens-files unity-lens-videos
   ```
4. Then Logout and Login. or try `unity --reset` command in the terminal.

If this method does not work, Try completely removing the configuration files. First make backup of your home dir and remove the configuration folders.

- Backup:

  ```
  sudo rsync -aP /home/your-user-name /home/your-user-name_old
  ```
- Remove configuration folders

  ```
  rm -r $HOME/.config
  rm -r $HOME/.compiz-1
  rm -r $HOME/.cache
  rm -r $HOME/.gconf
  ```
- Then try Logout and Login or `unity -reset` command.

Credit goes to [this forum post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1954519)

Comment: Thanks or the find!  A new issue, though.  Many things are crashing as I try to launch them.  It seems programs are unable to mkdir in the ~/.cache directory.  `** (gksu:5825): CRITICAL **: unable to create '/home/steve/.cache/dconf'; dconf will not work properly.
`

Comment: did you try `unity --reset`?

Comment: Yes, I actually had to reboot.  Although taking a closer look, root owned the cache folder in my home directory for some reason!  Is that supposed to be?  However, I chown'd it back to steve:steve and all seems well.  Was that the correct solution?